# ReStructuredText numbered headers

Tags: markup, restructuredtext

Is there a way in rst to have automatic header numbering ? That is something like:

```
#. Some Section
===============
...
#. Some Subsection
------------------
...
#. Another Subsection
---------------------
...
#. Another Section
==================
...
```

that would be rendered as:

## 1. Some Section

...

### 1.1 Some Subsection

...

### 1.2 Another Subsection

...

## 2. Another Section

...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the docutils manual, you can use the `sectnum` directive: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/0.7/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#automatic-section-numbering

So you can add something like this in the very first line(s):

```
.. sectnum::
```

HTH

Comment: Duh, how did I miss it ? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to skip the top level so it stills appears as a general title and not as 
"1 General Title"?

Comment: Answer to myself:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010158/do-not-number-the-section-header-in-restructuredtext?rq=1