# Textile numbered headers

Tags: markup, textile

Like [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362197/restructuredtext-numbered-headers), but for textile, is it possible to instruct textile, that headers should be numbered?

So

```
h1. first section
h1. second section
h2. subsection
```

would be rendered like:

## 1. first section

## 2. second section

### 2.1. subsection

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the <ol><li> tags, see below. Note there is a white space after the header tags .h1{space} that can't be seen in the example.

```
<ol> 

.h1 
<li>first section

.h1 
<li>second section

<ol>

h2. 
<li>subsection
```