# Do not number the section header in restructuredText

Tags: github, restructuredtext

The restructured text document

```
.. sectnum:

Document Title
==============
BlaBla

First section
-------------

BlaBla

Second section
--------------

BlaBla
```

gets rendered like this:

> ## 1. Document title
>
> BlaBla
>
> ### 1.1. First section
>
> BlaBla
>
> ### 1.2. Second section
>
> BlaBla

How do I achieve the following?

> ## Document title
>
> BlaBla
>
> ### 1. First section
>
> BlaBla
>
> ### 2. Second section
>
> BlaBla

Ideally in a way that works with GitHub’s restructuredText renderer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that

```
Document Title
==============
.. contents::
.. sectnum::

BlaBla

First section
-------------

BlaBla

Second section
--------------

BlaBla
```

Does the trick, as seen for example in https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0477-unicode-ellipsis.rst

Answer (score 0):

The given example misses a second colon after the
"sectnum" directive. Fixing this, the output of plain "Docutils" shows the intended styling (first heading promoted to a document title without section number).

Maybe, in the original document, there was some other text above the first heading?
A section heading becomes the document title only if it is the first visible element.
(Headers are allowed before the title, too.)